# Nativescript RadListView get scroll Y

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I am using Nativescript with telerik and i need to get the scroll position of a RadListView, because i need to know what item is the first visible item on the users screen after scrolling.

Is there any possibility to do this with nativescript or with native ios/android code inside it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This really depends on how you are planning on tracking it;

You can use *itemSwipeProgressChanged*, *itemSwipeProgressStarted*, *itemSwipeProgressEnded* events and the event will give you the itemIndex of the item that has scrolled into view...

Comment: These functions only trigger when i swipe left or right and not when i scroll up or down. Your answer in an other topic triggered me to update from 1.6.3 to 2.0.0 and now i can use element.getLocationRelativeTo() [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36918477/overlay-positioning-in-nativescript)