# Overlay positioning in NativeScript

Tags: nativescript

I'm working on a nativescript plugin for a material-inspired dropdown list of sorts. The plugin adds an AbsoluteLayout to the Page to act as a backdrop, then adds a ListView to that AbsoluteLayout so that the picker is displayed on top. It also adds a GridView with label and such that gets put in the position defined by its XML. Here's an example of the plugin in use in a view's XML:

```
<GridLayout rows="auto" columns="*, auto">
    <StackLayout>
        <label text="Color" />
        <label style="height: 3; background-color: gray;" />
    </StackLayout>

    <MDL:MaterialDropdownList col="1" id="ddlColors"
        items="{{ colors }}" selectedIndex="{{ selectedColorIndex }}" >
    </MDL:MaterialDropdownList>
</GridLayout>
```

What I'm wanting to do is display the ListView directly over the `MaterialDropdownList` element when it's tapped. However, I've tried going by the originX and originY, all the way up through each parent element until I hit the Page, and I get back a super low number of "2". Here's a snippet:

```
let src: viewModule.View = <viewModule.View>arg.object,
        x: number, y: number;
x = src.originX;
y = src.originY;
let parent = src.parent;
while (parent !== this.page) {
    x += parent.originX;
    y += parent.originY;
    parent = parent.parent;
}

console.log(`x and y are ${x} and ${y}`); //2, 2

this._listPicker.originX = x;
this._listPicker.originY = y;
```

Any thoughts greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is element.getLocationOnScreen() 
or element.getLocationInWindow() to get the actual position of the element.